# x86 128-bit atomic ops

Tags: assembly, x86, atomic, x86-64

How would you achieve 128-bit atomic operations in x86?

Intel's System Programming Guide, Part 1, 8.1 Locked Atomic Operations specifies guaranteed 16-, 32-, and 64-bit atomic operations.  So, can you achieve 128-bit atomic operations by doing 2 64-bit ops with the LOCK prefix?  Something like...

```
LOCK mov 64bits->addr
LOCK mov 64bits->addr+64bits
```

Aparently SSE has 128-bit XMM registers.  Can you just do 128-bit compare-and-swap using these registers?

Comment: You can do an atomic 16-byte compare-exchange (`CMPXCHG16B`).

Comment: Are you trying to do this in 32-bit x86, or in x64?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `LOCK` Prefix can not be used in combination with `MOV` instruction.

> The LOCK prefix can be prepended only to the following instructions and only to those forms of the instructions where the destination operand is a memory operand: ADD, ADC, AND, BTC, BTR, BTS, CMPXCHG, CMPXCH8B, DEC, INC, NEG, NOT, OR, SBB, SUB, XOR, XADD, and XCHG. [Intel Instruction Set Reference](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/)

Doing so will generate an **Invalid Opcode Exception**. So `LOCK CMPXCHG16B` is the only way here.

Comment: Concerning Intel Instruction Set Reference a 'LOCK' is required. "This instruction can be used with a LOCK prefix to allow the instruction to be executed atomically. To simplify the interface to the processor’s bus, the destination operand receives a write cycle without regard to the result of the comparison."

Comment: @brooksbp: there are [use-cases for `cmpxchg` without `lock`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44273130/224132), e.g. uniprocessor systems for use on memory other than an MMIO port.  That also makes it consistent with memory-destination `add` and other instructions that do have obvious uses other than concurrency.