# Assembly: does xadd instruction need lock?

Tags: assembly, x86, atomic, smp

I'm reading smphello.s code by allan cruse [code](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~cruse/cs630f06/smphello.s)

in the following part he's trying to setup stack segment for each processor.

the point is that he used xadd without using lock prefix while in the description of xadd as in [here](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_327.html) . there may be a lock prefix.

is this a bug or is it okay ? and why ?

```
# setup an exclusive stack-area for this processor
mov  $0x1000, %ax   # paragraphs in segment
xadd %ax, newSS     # 'atomic' xchg-and-add
mov  %ax, %ss       # segment-address in SS
xor  %esp, %esp     # top-of-stack into ESP
```

Comment: Yes it should use `lock`. The only instruction that sets lock by itself is `xchg`.

Comment: @becks: Is there a problem with my answer?

Answer (score 11):

`xadd` without `lock` is atomic wrt. *interrupts* on this core, but not wrt. code running on other cores (or DMA).  Just like all other memory-destination RMWs other than `xchg`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27837731/is-x86-cmpxchg-atomic-if-so-why-does-it-need-lock/44273130#44273130) which covers the same question for `cmpxchg`.

If this code runs simultaneously on multiple cores, 2 or more cores could read the same value for `newSS`, effectively losing an increment and assigning the same `ss:esp` to both cores.  Or one store could be delayed across multiple xadd's by other cores that happen to be sequential, "rewinding" the counter to some previous value seen by later loads.  Or any combination of problems.  [Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39393850)

Assuming `newSS` is aligned, the load and store are separately atomic, but do *not* form an atomic RMW.

If multiple cores are woken simultaneously (are broadcast IPIs possible?) it seems very possible for this to be a real problem.  If not, it's likely that each `xadd` would finish before the next core gets to this code.   (Including the store committing to L1d cache; becoming globally visible.)  But that's just a "happens to work" behaviour unless the core-wakeup function waits to hear back from one core before waking another.

**It definitely needs `lock xadd` if it wants to match the comment about an atomic increment.**  Being atomic wrt. interrupts is fine if threads never run concurrently, only via context switch on a single core.  (e.g. atomicity between the main thread and a signal handler, or interrupt handler on the same core).  But since this is titled `smphello.s`, uniprocessor assumptions seem unlikely.

Answer (score 11):

Just to provide some empirical evidence for these theoretical arguments:

Here is a test case where several threads use `xadd` to increment a shared counter.  On an i7-8565U with 4 cores, it outputs

```
unlocked: counter = 1633267, expected 4000000
locked: counter = 4000000, expected 4000000
```

which clearly shows that `xadd` without `lock` is NOT atomic.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

unsigned long counter = 0;

#define COUNTS_PER_THREAD 1000000UL
#define THREADS 4

void *unlocked_worker(void *unused) {
    (void)unused;
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < COUNTS_PER_THREAD; i++) {
        unsigned long inc = 1;
        asm volatile("xaddq %0, %1" : "+r" (inc), "+m" (counter));
    }
    return NULL;
}

void *locked_worker(void *unused) {
    (void)unused;
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < COUNTS_PER_THREAD; i++) {
        unsigned long inc = 1;
        asm volatile("lock; xaddq %0, %1" : "+r" (inc), "+m" (counter));
    }
    return NULL;
}

void run_threads(int lock) {
    void *(*worker)(void *) = lock ? locked_worker : unlocked_worker;
    counter = 0;
    pthread_t th[THREADS];
    for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++) {
        int err = pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, worker, NULL);
        if (err != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "pthread_create: %s\n", strerror(err));
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < THREADS; i++) {
        int err = pthread_join(th[i], NULL);
        if (err != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "pthread_join: %s\n", strerror(err));
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    printf("%s: counter = %lu, expected %lu\n",
           lock ? "locked" : "unlocked",
           counter, COUNTS_PER_THREAD * THREADS);
}

int main(void) {
    run_threads(0);
    run_threads(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After another thought to it, another scenario for this case came to my mind.

if the microcode implementation of `xadd` be like this:

```
temp = ax + newSS
newSS = ax 
ax = temp ; the last 2 are actual xchg
```

then we have problem in this scenario:

Assume that `newSS` is shared between 2 threads.

Thread No.0 (`t0` with it's `ax` equals to *5*) loads and adds `newSS` with `ax` and put it into a `temp register`.

Assume that At this point we have a context switch. Then `t1` with it's `ax` equals to *5* tries to load `newSS` and add it to `ax` and put the result in the `temp register`. and then a context switch back to `t0`...
Both stack segment registers will point to the same address.

Obviously we have a problem here. Unless the microcode implementation be like this:

```
tmp register = ax
xchg ax, newSS
ax = ax + tmpRegister
```

in any other way that variable `newSS` is read more than once or read and written in different instructions, we need lock.

Comment: As I commented on your other answer, there's no benefit to describing it in terms of `xchg`.  There is no atomic RMW; the microcode implementation is *not* like your 2nd code block.  ([Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39393850))

Comment: Related: [Is x86 CMPXCHG atomic, if so why does it need LOCK?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44273130) describes the uniprocessor use-cases for `cmpxchg` without `lock`.

Comment: But note that **the danger isn't context switches, it's other cores running the same code at the *same* time and having 2 or more threads read the same value**, losing an increment and assigning the same `ss:esp` to both cores.  (And then storing the same value twice for later threads.)  The whole instruction is indivisible wrt. interrupts, but not wrt. memory operations from other cores.