# How following codes can make a Big Kernel Lock?

Tags: assembly, x86, locking, atomic

```
MPgetlock_edx:
1:
    movl    (%edx), %eax
    movl    %eax, %ecx
    andl    $CPU_FIELD,%ecx
    cmpl    _cpu_lockid, %ecx
    jne 2f
    incl    %eax
    movl    %eax, (%edx)
    ret
2:
    movl    $FREE_LOCK, %eax
    movl    _cpu_lockid, %ecx
    incl    %ecx
    lock
    cmpxchg %ecx, (%edx)
    jne 1b
    GRAB_HWI
    ret
```

1. Why upper function can implement a Big kernel Lock (BKL)?
2. 'cmpxchg' is atomic? why 'lock' needed before it?  (This part is a duplicate of [Is x86 CMPXCHG atomic, if so why does it need LOCK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27837731/is-x86-cmpxchg-atomic-if-so-why-does-it-need-lock))
3. Why not 'movl (%edx), %ecx' directly?

Comment: The first part of the function checks if the CPU already has the lock. If it does, the counter is incremented. If not an CAS (`lock cmpxchg`) is used to try to acquire the lock. `cmpxchg` is not atomic without a `lock` prefix (you were probably thinking of `xchg`) and `mov` is totally different from `cmpxchg` (see Compare-And-Swap).

Comment: Part 2 is a duplicate of [Is x86 CMPXCHG atomic, if so why does it need LOCK?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44273130), but we can't close multi-part questions as duplicates of only one part.  (That's one reason Stack Overflow discourages multi-part questions.)