# x86: Instruction reorder related with `cmpxchg` (without lock prefix)?

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, atomic, compare-and-swap, instruction-reordering

Could a memory write instruction (`mov reg to memory`) after `cmpxchg` (without lock prefix) be recordered and executed before `cmpxchg` for x86?

EX1:

```asm
    // try_cmpxchg_local(&local.pos, &tail, tail + 1)
I1: cmpxchg dword ptr [rsi], edi

    // now the tail-th position is reserved
    // WRITE_ONCE(local.dat, value);
I2: mov qword ptr [r11], r10
```

The question is: could I2 be reordered before I1? *I'm assuming it's a YES since there are no dependencies between I2 and I2.* (**It's wrong, should be a NO.**)

How about other architectures (weak consistency especially)? Need a `sfence` between I1 and I2 to guarantee the order?

EX2: the actual example in reality will have a conditional branch  like this:

```asm
    // try_cmpxchg_local(&local.pos, &tail, tail + 1)
I1: cmpxchg dword ptr [rsi], edi
    cmp edx, eax
    jnz ...

    // now the tail-th position is reserved
    // WRITE_ONCE(local.dat, value);
I2: mov qword ptr [r11], r10
```

So for EX2, with spectre mitigated, I2 won't happen before I1. Am I right?

Comment: [The `cmpxchg()` macro in the Linux kernel emits the `lock cmpxchg` instruction on x86](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/tools/arch/x86/include/asm/cmpxchg.h#L86), so I think your question is based on a false premise.  The point of the macro is to perform an *atomic* compare-exchange.  A non-atomic compare-exchange would be rather useless.

Comment: But generally, when writing in a higher-level language, you don't want to be thinking about the behavior of the underlying instructions, because there's always the possibility that the compiler emits some different instructions than you are expecting.  Instead, think in terms of the abstract memory model defined by the language.  In the case of the Linux kernel, it has [its own memory model](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt), distinct from that defined by the ISO C standard.

Comment: Thanks, @NateEldredge. I just updated the codes to make it clear.

Comment: In x86 assembly, no, `mov [r11], r10` can't become visible until after the preceding `cmpxchg`, because x86's memory model is program order + a store buffer with store forwarding.  Every store is a release-store, so LoadStore and StoreStore reordering aren't allowed.  [C++ How is release-and-acquire achieved on x86 only using MOV?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60314179)

Comment: The main reason `lock` is used with cmpxchg is to make it an atomic RMW, instead of separate load and store ops.  [Is x86 CMPXCHG atomic, if so why does it need LOCK?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27837731).  That also promotes it from `memory_order_acq_rel` to `seq_cst` in ISO C++ terms.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the correction. Your description is more accurate: I2 can't *be visible* before I1. I just examined Intel® 64 Architecture Memory Ordering White Paper (https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~410-f10/doc/Intel_Reordering_318147.pdf). Much to my surprise, Intel x64 memory model is more strict than what I ever thought. Here are the quatations:

Intel 64 memory ordering obeys the following principles:
1. Loads are not reordered with other loads.
2. Stores are not reordered with other stores.
3. Stores are not reordered with older loads.
4.  ...

Comment: Correct, like I said, program order plus a store buffer (with store-forwarding) fully explains what's architecturally allowed on x86, e.g. that loads can't reorder with other loads or later stores..  (CPUs actually load early, but roll back if they detect a memory order mis-speculation.)  See also https://preshing.com/20120930/weak-vs-strong-memory-models/